# Rails - undefined method `title'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to learn some Rails basics with [Getting Started with Rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html), but I can't seem to get pass an error:

```
undefined method `title' for nil:NilClass

Showing /blog/app/views/articles/show.html.erb where line #3 ...
```

I have Ruby 1.9.3, and Rails 4.1.0.

My **views/articles/show.html.erb** looks like this:

```
<p>
  <strong>Title:</strong>
  <%= @article.title %>   # line #3
</p>

<p>
  <strong>Text:</strong>
  <%= @article.text %>
</p>
```

My **controllers/articles_controller.rb** looks like that:

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
  end

  def create
    @article = Article.new(article_params)

    @article.save
    redirect_to @article
  end

  private
    def article_params
      params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
    end

  def new
  end

  def show
    @article = Article.find(params[:id])
  end

end
```

The error pops out whenever I try to create a new post through */articles/new*

Comment: Is the record actually created? Check in your console: `rails c`, then `Article.all`.

Comment: nil:NilClass is telling you it doesn't know of an object named Article

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The main issue you're facing is that your new & show methods are private since they come after the 'private' declaration within your class.

Move the code for new & show above the private declaration within your class and you should get things functioning. Also, pass article params into the find for show, since you're using Strong Parameters.

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController

  def index
   end

   def create
     @article = Article.new(article_params)

     @article.save
     redirect_to @article
   end


   def new
   end

   def show
     @article = Article.find(article_params)
   end

   private
     def article_params
       params.require(:article).permit(:title, :text)
     end

end
```

Comment: Oh, sorry. It's marked now. Turns out not only am I Rails newbie but also StackExchange's ;) Thanks for the help again!

Answer (score 0):

Check if the article is created - since it is nil:NilClass I suppose note.

Try to add the following in new method:

```
def new
     @article = Article.new
end
```

If this still doesn't solve it, please post the new view & server output when saving the item.

Comment: Oh and the new & show is private as ice rightfully mentioned.